# SSRS Server split into Dev and Prod

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've started a new role as a SSRS dev (I used to be QA) for a small company and the process is for me to create the reports and publish to Prod and someone reviews.

The problem is if I mess up (and I do) the users have to stop using the reports.

The question is, can we some how make our reporting server into a Dev/QA and Prod so reports can be checked before users see them.

Comment: I don't know that it's fleshed out enough to answer, but my company has each client set up with two folders on their report servers.  One is for Production level reports and another for testing.  That way you can upload the updated report to the test folder, have the client check it out, make any fixes, then push to the production folder.

Comment: Agree with @Steve-o169. Our company has the same setup. Different folders.

Comment: Thats a simple way of doing it. Guessing I can point the test report to the dev database to pick up any back end changes.

Comment: @lezs76 In my setup, we have data sources saved on the report server in a third folder.  And in my company, we actually have prod and test databases to work with as well as a public facing data server.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Thanks for the info. I'll pass it on and see if we can set up something like this.